# PDF Form data Submission Via REST API / Web Services

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I am having a PDF form that saves the data and validate the data entered by user e.g. a client information PDF document that takes client data and when user click on send button, it must post the data to the web service that further process it or saves to database.

I am using Acrobat Professional for this. Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat and Adobe Reader can submit form data to any URL using a button on the document and the "Submit a Form" action or via Acrobat JavaScript (probably unnecessary). You just need something on the server to interpret the data. If you submit as HTML, the submission will look just like query parameters where the key names are the same as the names of the fields and the values, same as the field values without the formatting. To the server, it looks like it was submitted from a standard HTML form so just about anything you have will be able to work with the submission.

You need to use Acrobat Pro to add this button to the document but then Standard and Reader can use it.

See https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/setting-action-buttons-pdf-forms.html

You can also submit as FDF or XFDF, an XML(ish) expression of FDF, in which case you'll want to use something like the FDF Toolkit to read it but based on your question, I don't think you need to do that.

#### 3rd party edit

Information from the linked page

> FDF
>
> Returns the user input without sending back the underlying PDF file.
> You can select options to include Field Data, Comments, and
> Incremental Changes To The PDF.
>
> XFDF
>
> Returns the user input as an XML file. You can include Comments with
> the field data or just the field data.